# CakePHP: if user did not come from the same website

Tags: php, cakephp

How would I check if the user did not come from the same website? So for example if a user types in the URL in the browser to a direct page then they would have accessed that page without coming from another page in the site.

So something like:

```
if(!user not from same url)
{
//do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$referer = env('HTTP_REFERER');

if(empty($referer) && $this->Session->check('Auth.redirect') == false)
{
    echo 'user didn\'t come website and wasn\'t redirect from the auth component';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$this->referer()` in controller?

Edit: Well, for your purpose, you can directly use this:

> ```
> $referer = env('HTTP_REFERER');
> if(empty($referer)){ echo 'jazz'; }
> ```

because $this->referer() behaves a little differently. It won't return false or null or empty string.

Comment: Gives me this error: `Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context`

Comment: This works great except that when a user is sent from a redirect such as when requested authentication to access a controller. CakePHP doesn't class this as a referrer so the code executes when a user has ACTUALLY come from the site but has automatically been redirected! Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: For example if you go here: http://driz.co.uk/admin/portfolio you will automatically be taken to the login form BUT see an echo saying you did not come from the website BUT in actual fact you have as you were redirected from another part but clearly CakePHP hasn't acknowledged this fact! (NOTE: this happens if you click a link to the admin portfolio section tooo!)

Comment: I'm not even sure what you are asking: is env('HTTP_REFERER') empty? You can check Session->read('Auth.redirect')